# Skipping test cases based on environment variable value (Java maven testNG Selenium automation)

Tags: java, selenium, maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

I use `mvn test -Denv=dev`, `mvn test -Denv=test`, or demo or prod to execute test cases. My `testNG.xml` is being trigged using `surefire plugin`. I have to skip a complete folder if `env = prod`.

I was trying to use `TestNG-${env}.xml` and have 4 testng.xml files for each env example: testNG-dev.xml etc and add only valid test cases(classes) in `testNG-prod.xml`. Not sure if this is the right approach and I am not sure how to pick testNG.xml as default if the env value is not passed. [Click here to view project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n2KKO.png)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    
                    <!-- <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>TestNG.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles> -->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Answer (score -1):

The simplest way is to define properties in your pom.xml (fyi, `env` - is very bad name for property):

```
<properties>
  <!-- 
      default value of target.env
  -->
  <target.env>dev</target.env>
<properties>

...


<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>${maven-surefire-plugin-version}</version>
  <configuration>
      <suiteXmlFiles>
        <suiteXmlFile>TestNG-${target.env}.xml</suiteXmlFile>
     </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

after that `mvn test` will use `dev` and `mvn test -Dtarget.env=xxx` will use environment specified